# randomly scattering grouped circles

Tags: json, d3.js

I am reading a lot about d3.js but every time when I try to do something new based on example projects it stop working. The latest one is based on Jerome Cukier's example on nested data (http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/05/28/manipulating-data-like-a-boss-with-d3/).

In this current project am having hard time scattering circles randomly in the rectangle, with out using the json data for the translation function. Beside that every thing seams working. I really appreciate if someone give me some clue!!

here is both json data and the script

mydata.json

```
 [

{ "stat": "ok",
        "id": "VR01",
        "servername": "Server_1",
        "cpu": 45, "mem": 25,
        "diskIO": 0, "bandwith": 200



}, { "stat": "attention",
        "id": "VR02",
        "servername": "Server_02",
        "cpu": 55, "mem": 35,
        "diskIO": 1, "bandwith": 2000


}, { "stat": "warning",
        "id": "VR03",
        "servername": "Server_03",
        "cpu": 98, "mem": 85,
        "diskIO": 1,
        "bandwith": 2000

}, { "stat": "dead",
        "id": "VR04",
        "servername": "Server_04",
        "cpu": 0, "mem": 0,
        "diskIO": 0,
        "bandwith": 0 }, { "stat": "ok",
        "id": "VR05",
        "servername": "Server_05",
        "cpu": 45, "mem": 25,
        "diskIO": 0, "bandwith": 200

}, { "stat": "attention",
        "id": "VR06",
        "servername": "Server_06",
        "cpu": 55, "mem": 35,
        "diskIO": 1, "bandwith": 2000


}, { "stat": "warning",
        "id": "VR07",
        "servername": "Server_07",
        "cpu": 98, "mem": 85,
        "diskIO": 1,
        "bandwith": 2000

}, { "stat": "dead",
        "id": "VR08",
        "servername": "Server_08",
        "cpu": 0, "mem": 0,
        "diskIO": 0,
        "bandwith": 0 }    
]
```

and

```
 <script>
    var width = 900,
            height = 300,
            margin = 50;


    var cwidth = 400, cheight = 300, cmargin = 10, maxr = 10;

    var svg = d3.select(".svg_element").append("svg");
    var x = 10;
    var y = 10;
    var o = 10;


    //var status = ["ok",  "attention", "warning", "dead"];

    var data;
    d3.json("mydata.json", function(json) {

        data = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {
            return d.stat;

        })
                .sortKeys(d3.descending)
                .entries(json);


        // One cell for each continent
        var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (400 * i) + ",1)";
        });
        // we add a rect element with a title element
        // so that mousing over the cell will tell us which continent it is
        g
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", cmargin)
                .attr("y", cmargin)
                .attr("width", cwidth - 2 * cmargin)
                .attr("height", cheight - 2 * cmargin)
                .append("title")
                .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        });
        // we also write its name below.
        g
                .append("text")
                .attr("y", cheight + 10)
                .attr("x", cmargin)
                .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        });

        // now marks, initiated to default values
        g.selectAll("circle")
                // we are getting the values of the countries like this:
                .data(function(d) {
            return d.values;
        })
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", cmargin)
                .attr("cy", cheight - cmargin)
                .attr("r", 5)
                // throwing in a title element
                .append("title")
                .text(function(d) {
            return d.servername;
        });

        // finally, we animate our marks in position
   // here is where am having problem putting the circles in the rectangle with out using the json data 

g.selectAll("circle").transition().duration(100)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(+d.cpu);
        })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(+d.mem);
        })
                .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return o(d.diskIO);
        })
                .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return o(+d.bandwith);
        });


       });

   </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kevintcoughlin/JV62X/)?

Comment: Hi i added the node variable on top like this nodes = d3.range(200).map(function() {
            return {
                radius: Math.random() * 12 + 4,
                cx: Math.random() * cwidth - 50,
                cy: Math.random() * cheight - 50};
        });

Comment: g.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(function(d) {
                return d.values;})
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", nodes[i].cx)
                    .attr("cy", nodes[i].cy)
                    .attr("r", nodes[i].radius)
                    .attr("fill", function() {
                return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ", 100%, 75%)";}).append("title") .text(function(d) {
           return d.servername;
            });    since the for loop in d3 is equivalent of .enter still no luck

Comment: When you say "no luck", what do you mean?

Comment: it creates the circle randomly in one of the rectangle(g), what i wanted was to create the circle which represent one server in their nested group while they scattered in their recttangle randomly but with the exact numbers based on json data like the example project http://www.jeromecukier.net/stuff/data%20example/data-example3.html

Comment: Ok, so you would have to restrict the random coordinate created to the area of the rectangle, i.e. `var x = rectX + Math.random() * rectWidth;` and similar for y.

Comment: thanks for your comments as i have  said i am new to d3  and am sorry for not getting your suggestion. the code that i have in github works correctly  in creating the rectangle and the circle based on json data, even when you put the cursers on each circle  it tells you the server name. the problem is the circles are located on the right bottom of each rectangle overlapped which is their default position . then in the example project it moves them using translate.duration function but to do that i dont want to depend on the data like on the example project. i wish i can send you the screenshot

Comment: Now I'm confused -- where do you get the coordinates for the circles? From the data or do you want to generate them randomly to fall within the rectangle?

Comment: since they are created already i want them to fall within the rectangle

Comment: is it ok if i send you the out put as screenshot with your email

Comment: I know what you want to do -- you need to set the coordinates as I've outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the dimensions of the rectangles you're generating for into account when generating the random positions. Apart from that, it should be straightforward:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return cmargin + Math.random() * (cwidth - cmargin);
    })
.attr("cy", function(d) {
        return cmargin + Math.random() * (cheight - cmargin);
    });
```

Complete example [here](https://vida.io/documents/eFcXpYMYCZ5cGZHJw).